# How to remove my facebook app from user

Tags: android, facebook

I have an Android app that uses Facebook login. When the user presses logout button, my app is closing opened sessions. But my Facebook app is still authenticated in user's profile. I want to remove my Facebook app from user's Facebook applications. (https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)

Is that possible on Android?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure deleting it your app from the user's applications is what you want? How are you closing your session?

Comment: Sorry for my inattention, thanks @Igy